# Missing semicolon on non-null assertion

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have this function where I order a group of cards based on a coordinate system:

```
const orderCardsInPage = (items: OrderItemType[], pageCards: CardType[]) => {
    return pageCards.sort((firstCard, secondCard) => {
        const orderItemOfFirstCard = items.find((orderItem: OrderItemType) => orderItem.card === firstCard._id.toString());
        const orderItemOfSecondCard = items.find((orderItem: OrderItemType) => orderItem.card === secondCard._id.toString());
        const valueOfFirstOrderItem = orderItemOfFirstCard?.value;
        const valueOfSecondOrderItem = orderItemOfSecondCard?.value;
        return valueOfFirstOrderItem! - valueOfSecondOrderItem!;
    });
};
```

However, when I try to compile, my `return` statement throws a `missing semicolon` error on the non-null assertion symbol `(!)`.

I know that the `array.find()` function might return an undefined, that's why I have the non-null assertion in place. How can I fix this?

Comment: Why not just do the assertion where you call `find`? `.find(...)!`

Comment: Not reproducible.

Comment: Please consider providing a [mre] that demonstrates your issue when pasted, as-is, into a standalone IDE.  Right now I only see warnings about `OrderItemType` and `CardType` not being defined and I don't see any "missing semicolon" error. If you can help others reproduce the issue, they can help you fix it.  (If you do [edit] this into a reproducible example and want me to take another look, please comment and mention @jcalz so I'm notified.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't reproduce the error, but what you could do is make sure the values are defined, that way you don't need a non null assertion.

```
const orderCardsInPage = (items: { value: number }[], pageCards: { _id: number }[]) => {
  return pageCards.sort((firstCard, secondCard) => {
    const orderItemOfFirstCard = items.find((orderItem: any) => orderItem.card === firstCard._id.toString());
    const orderItemOfSecondCard = items.find((orderItem: any) => orderItem.card === secondCard._id.toString());
    const valueOfFirstOrderItem = orderItemOfFirstCard?.value;
    const valueOfSecondOrderItem = orderItemOfSecondCard?.value;
    // for example throw if not found
    if (!valueOfFirstOrderItem || !valueOfSecondOrderItem) throw new Error("No item found");
    return valueOfFirstOrderItem - valueOfSecondOrderItem;
  });
};
```

Btw I assumed the types, if the `value` prop is not optional, you could do the check earlier

```
const orderCardsInPage = (items: { value: number }[], pageCards: { _id: number }[]) => {
  return pageCards.sort((firstCard, secondCard) => {
    const orderItemOfFirstCard = items.find((orderItem: any) => orderItem.card === firstCard._id.toString());
    const orderItemOfSecondCard = items.find((orderItem: any) => orderItem.card === secondCard._id.toString());

    if (!orderItemOfFirstCard || !orderItemOfSecondCard) throw new Error("No item found");
    return orderItemOfFirstCard.value - orderItemOfSecondCard.value;
  });
};
```